# Splitting consteval from non-consteval expressions in parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

My goal is to use C++20 to write a new format library, which can write a log line that generally looks like this:

```cpp
Log(
    Error,
    If(result == false),
    Title("Operation failed"),
    "Failed to execute task, ID: {}",
    taskId);
```

Which takes:

1. Any number of "Log Traits" (`Error`, `If`, `Title`), to be evaluated at runtime
2. A format string + any number of args as the message, to be formatted using `std::format_to`

The issue is that I want to use `std::format_to` for its compile type format checking, which requires that the string `"Failed to execute task, ID: {}"` must remain consteval for it to be turned into a `std::format_string<...>`, but I don't want every "Log Trait" to also be consteval, because some need to be evaluated at runtime, such as `If`.

My current attempt has me defining a `LogTrait` concept, which `Error`, `If` and `Title` all adhere to:

```cpp
template<typename T> concept LogTrait = ...
```

That I use to try to skip all the traits, and get right to the format string:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
consteval auto GetFormatString(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_pair(fmt, std::make_format_args(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template<typename... Args>
constexpr auto GetFormatString(LogTrait auto&&, Args&&... args)
{
    return GetFormatString(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

But if I make both functions consteval, it'll error because `If` can't be resolved at compile time, and if I make either function merely constexpr, then the format string can't be converted to `std::format_string` since it can only be consteval constructed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use fmt library.

Comment: I would argue that a sane conditional logging function should be a macro that wraps the string into the lambda, to avoid computing it if the condition is false.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to sidestep this by changing how you call the `Log` function:

```cpp
Log
    .Error
    .If(result == false)
    .Title("Operation failed")
    ("Failed to execute task, ID: {}", taskId);


Log(
    Error,
    If(result == false),
    Title("Operation failed")
)("Failed to execute task, ID: {}",
    taskId);

// Or make a new "LogTrait" to hold the format string with it's args
Log(
    Error,
    If(result == false),
    Title("Operation {} failed", name),  // This should also be a format string
    Body("Failed to execute task, ID: {}", taskId));
```

---

It *is* possible, albeit difficult, to maintain your current syntax. Once you've passed `"Failed to execute task, ID: {}"` as a `const char(&)[N]` or `const char*` argument, you can't construct a format_string (since it can't be `consteval`), and using `vformat` gets rid of type safety, so you have to do something else.

So, you have to make `Log` a template struct, so you can deduce the type of the arguments then deduce the type of the `Log` struct so your `format_string` can have the right type.

Say this is the ultimate function you want to call:

```cpp
template<LogTrait... Traits, typename... Args>
void do_log(std::tuple<Traits...> traits, std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args) {
    // ...
}
```

You can implement `Log` like this:

```cpp
template<typename Traits, typename Args>
struct Log;

template<typename... Traits, typename... Args>
struct Log<std::tuple<Traits...>, std::tuple<Args...>>{
    Log(const Log&) = delete;
    Log& operator=(const Log&) = delete;
    ~Log() = default;

    Log(Traits&&... traits, std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args) {
        do_log(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Traits>(traits)...), fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<std::size_t Offset, typename... Args, std::size_t... I>
auto tuple_index(std::index_sequence<I...>) -> std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Offset + I, std::tuple<Args...>>...>;

template<std::size_t N, typename... Args>
using tuple_of_first = decltype(tuple_index<0, Args...>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));
template<std::size_t N, typename... Args>
using tuple_of_last = decltype(tuple_index<sizeof...(Args)-N, Args...>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

// Index of the first non-LogTrait argument, the format string
template<typename... Args>
inline constexpr std::size_t format_string_index = []<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    constexpr std::size_t format_string_index = std::min({ LogTrait<Args> ? std::size_t(-1) : I... });
    static_assert(format_string_index != std::size_t(-1), "Log(...): No format string");
    return format_string_index;
}(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});

template<typename... Args>
struct traits_argument {
    using type = tuple_of_first<format_string_index<Args...>, Args...>;
};

template<typename... Args>
struct format_argument {
    using type = tuple_of_last<sizeof...(Args) - 1u - format_string_index<Args...>, Args...>;
};

template<typename... Args>
Log(Args&&... args) -> Log<typename traits_argument<Args...>::type, typename format_argument<Args...>::type>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EbrYheYPW

Comment: Well that's an impressive answer in a short amount of time, thank you so much for the advice and code! I'll give it a whirl!